# Country list is not showing in NgxIntlTelInput angular plugin

Tags: angular

In my form I have a field to input telephone. To input country code with telephone I have used [NgxIntlTelInput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input) angular plugin. The code is below:

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ngx-intl-tel-input 
            [cssClass]="'custom'" 
            [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
            [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" 
            [enablePlaceholder]="true" 
            [searchCountryFlag]="true"
            [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]" 
            [selectFirstCountry]="true"
            [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.India" 
            [maxLength]="15" 
            [phoneValidation]="true"
            [separateDialCode]="separateDialCode" 
            [numberFormat]="PhoneNumberFormat.National" 
            name="phone"
            formControlName="phone">
        </ngx-intl-tel-input>
    </div>    
</form>

export class NgxTelephoneComponent implements OnInit {
  phoneForm: FormGroup;

  separateDialCode = false;
  SearchCountryField = SearchCountryField;
  CountryISO = CountryISO;
  PhoneNumberFormat = PhoneNumberFormat;
  preferredCountries: CountryISO[] = [CountryISO.UnitedStates, CountryISO.UnitedKingdom];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.phoneForm = new FormGroup({
      phone: new FormControl(undefined, [Validators.required])
    });
  }
}
```

But the problem is Country list is not showing. Below is output:
[image]

Actual output should be like this:
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-10 it should be fine tho

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
npm install google-libphonenumber --save
```